# rails import with on_duplicate_key_update not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I use on duplicate key update, the same records will be added all the time, and the existing data cannot be updated.

I have added an indexes.

`add_index :my_table, [:month, :media_id, :campaign_type], name: "index_table"`

code

```
result = [{ media_id: 1, campaign_type: 1, month: "2022/08/01", report: [ "impression"=>1000, "cost"=>5000]}]

My_table.import result, on_duplicate_key_update: [:report]
```

Comment: Did you add a plain index or a unique index?

Comment: I set it to unique index and it work！ Thank you so much！